# Better pattern for choosing constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constructor

I have class `Foo`, which have more than one constructor.

```
class Foo
{
public:
Foo( Param1, Param2 );
Foo( Param1, Param3, Param4 );
Foo( Param1, Param4 );
Foo( Param1, Param2, Param4 );
}
```

Actual list of params to constructor is large and I don't want to provide access to these constructors directly from other projects ( otherwise I would need to export these 4 constructors ). I know best pattern to avoid such multiple constructor is *Builder Pattern*. But that would create confusion for clients of this class about which param is optional and which param is not. In addition each constructor certain validation based on parameters. So I would need common place to do such validation before actually using any method on this object.

So currently what we are planning is something as below:

1. No change `Foo` class.
2. Define `FooParam` Struct

   ```
   struct FooParam
   {
       Param1 p1;
       Param2 p2;
       Param3 p3;
       Param4 p4;
   }
   ```
3. Factory:

   ```
   Foo* CreateFoo( FooParams& foo )
   {
       if( foo.Param2 )
       {
           if( foo.Param4 )
           {
               return new Foo( foo.param1, foo.param2, foo.param4);
           }
           else
               return  new Foo( foo.param1, foo.param2);
       }
       else if( foo.param4 )
       {
           if(foo.param3)
               return new Foo( foo.param1, foo.param3, foo.param4 );
           else
               return new Foo( foo.param1, foo.param4 );
       }

       throw new Exception("Invalid Parameter" );
   }
   ```

I think we can do better at step 3. But now sure how?

Comment: What are the data types for param1....?

Comment: There is the option of default values as well

Comment: The advantage of multiple constructor is that it is very clear which parameters go together. The `struct FooParam` seems make everything a lot complicated. Why can't you export the constructors?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose your constructors for some reasons, you can easily hide them behind a factory method based on templates and perfect forwarding:

```
class Foo {
    // defined somewhere
    Foo( Param1, Param2 );
    Foo( Param1, Param3, Param4 );
    Foo( Param1, Param4 );
    Foo( Param1, Param2, Param4 );

private:
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto factory(Args&&... args) {
        Foo foo{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        // do whatever you want here
        return foo;
    }
}
```

No need to throw anything at runtime.
If a constructor that accepts those parameters doesn't exist, you'll receive a compile-time error.

---

Otherwise, another idiomatic way of doing that is by using [named constructors](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor).
I copy-and-paste directly the example from the link above:

```
class Game {
public:
    static Game createSinglePlayerGame() { return Game(0); }
    static Game createMultiPlayerGame() { return Game(1); }

protected:
    Game (int game_type);
};
```

Not sure this fits your requirements anyway.

---

That said, think about what's the benefit of doing this:

```
CreateFoo({ Param1V, Param3V });
```

Or even worse, this:

```
FooParams params{ Param1V, Param3V };
CreateFoo(params);
```

Instead of this:

```
new Foo{Param1V, Param3V};
```

By introducing an intermediate class you are not actually helping the users of your class.
They still have to remember what are the required params for the specific case.

Answer (score -1):

As an user, I prefer

```
Foo* CreateFoo(Param1* P1, Param2* P2, Param3* P3, Param4* P4);
```

Why should I construc a `struct` just to pass some (maybe NULL) parameters?